# Bizarre encoding of url (query string?)

Tags: encryption, get, cryptography, httprequest

I'm on a ukrainian website (http://www.microtron.ua/) and when you enter a search term (ie. acer) you end up with a bizarre encoded url (http://www.microtron.ua/goods#c0#0#0#x97x99x101x114#3#1#25#0#0). Has anyone seen anything like this before? And what kind of encoding technique is this? And how can it be decrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no query string, it is a proprietary  REST request.

```
x97x99x101x114
```

in the request is an weirdly encoded ASCII string: 97 is 'a', 99 is 'c', 101 = 'e', 114 = 'r'.

The rest of # separated fields could identify your language, input field etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a proprietary encoding, it is essentially a REST request. It is not a query string, there is no ? character.